# Cycles either not rendering, or giving warped result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I was working on simple low-poly starship, and one moment I decided to get a rendered view, but something went wrong. When I entered rendered view, it was stuck at initializing. Funny enough, render through F12 still worked, but provided warped results. The rendered view started working when I imported the model into another blend file, but it still provided warped result (some of the faces were missing):
[image: Screenshot of the defects]

But solid view (and any view besides rendered) still showed the model as it should look like:
[image: Material preview screenshot]

I am really confused, I tried recalculating normals, removed bevel, tried changing render settings, applied all transforms, and still no change at all. Here is blend that can't even initialize cycles: [image]

Upd: After saving the file without texturing and uploading it, i noticed that there are no more missing faces (i don't know why), but rendered view is still not working.

Comment: It would be very surprising if someone guesses the problem without seeing the file. You should [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/181909/edit) your question and add the file that would have the issue reproducible.

Comment: I know, i will add it the moment I am able, which should be in a few minutes

Comment: Most likely True Displacement (which is only enabled in render view) or a modifier that’s enabled for render but not for preview.